# how to integrate social media (Facebook, Flickr, Instagram) in my photo workflow?

Tags: photos.app, photos, facebook, picasa, instagram

I currently use Picasa on OSX to sort and edit my photos. Then I upload to Facebook, Flickr, and Tumblr. I tag people on Facebook and Flickr separately; and I add locations separately; I add dates.

I write captions in Picasa, then I have to reenter them in each social media site.

It's a tedious, redundant process.

Is there an app (iPhoto? something else?) that integrates with Facebook and Google Maps so I can tag my friends, add locations, and write captions directly in an OSX app, then upload my photos to Facebook/Flickr/Instagram with the face-tags and location-tags and captions pre-loaded?